# How to force Calendar sync with ContentObserver?

Tags: android, calendar, synchronization

I implemented specific application for calendar events editing - create, edit, delete. It uses ContentObserver as shown in many examples. All works fine except one - the calendar on my test device often does not sync with server until I run Calendar application. I mean - my app creates event properly. It stores somewhere on the device. Then I check this calendar on Google server through Web interface. This event sometimes appear on server right now but most of time it does not appear. It can not appear during whole day. But when I start Google Calendar app on my device - event appears in it and immediately on server.

More - back syncing works in same manner. I create event in Web interface. It won't appear on my device until I run Google Calendar app. Only after I run it - event appears in it and in my app. Same if I change event on server. Only if Calendar app is open and running - then event appear on my device immediately.

The Auto synchronization option is ON in Android settings.

I do not know how force calendar sync immediately after event created or changed except one way - start Google Calendar app from my app. But this is monstrous...

Is there any other way to force Android Calendar sync right now after event created except run Calendar app?